# How to determine dataset quality in sentiment analysis when all else fails?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, sentiment-analysis

Im working on a semester assignment doing sentiment analysis on a dataset with norwegian text. It comes "pre-split" in three files, train, test and dev. there is a high imbalance in the dataset with the classes respectively constituting, neutral: 50-55% or more, Positive: 30-33%, negative: 15-17% for each dataset. The problem im facing is that the models fails to carry its learned behavior from the training set, overfitting after it reaches close to 65% accuracy on the validation set. What can i do to fix this? How can i proceed to analyze data in a clear and "correct" format to prove it's impossible to get higher scores. (Nobody else in my class has passed 65% on test or validation. Task assignment says it may be impossible to get good results on one of the tasks(Perfect/great scores for other tasks).

The measures taken to fix the issue:
Different text processing techniques, different word embeddings, no word embeddings, padding, int sequencing
Different model structures: LSTM, multinomialNB, Logistic Regression, SpaCy text classifier, Bidirectional LSTM
Layers: Dropout, SpatialDropout1D, Dropout, spacy word embeddings (Covers 90% of processed text),
Model architecture: Different layers, neurons, activation (All types), recurrent dropout, regularization and more
Current architecture working the best:

```py
# Define model architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Embedding layer initializes embeddings with our matrix, applying them to our entries, set as trainable
model.add(Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],),weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=True))
#Randomly dropping some entries
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.3))
#bidirecitonal LSTM with dropout layers and regularisation
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=64, activation='tanh', dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001))))
#Dropout to drop features
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#Classifying sentiment
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.1)))
#summarizing model to see architecture
model.summary()
```

Hyperparameters: Tweaking learning rate, class weights, oversampling minority clases, undersampling majority classes
Also tried changing batch size, epochs, Early stopping...
Trainable has been changed between true and false, no improvements.

Comment: How large are the three datasets, and do you have access to them all?
BTW, 50:33:17 is not too imbalanced. Many real-world datasets (fraud, disease, etc.) can be 100:1 or much higher.